# How can i incorporate ASIHTTPRequest with Blocks into an GCD Concurrent Queue

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

How can i incorporate ASIHTTPRequest with Blocks into an GCD Concurrent Queue

**Currently i am doing using this way**. I don't want to compare GCD Queues and ASINetworkQueue. Here i am using GCD Queues and want to know is i am doing correct

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/news_detail/",tagID];  
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; 

__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedWhenStaleCachePolicy | ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];   
[request setDelegate:self];


[request setCompletionBlock:^{

dispatch_queue_t JSONProcessingQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(JSONProcessingQueue, ^{


        dispatch_sync(JSONProcessingQueue, ^{
            NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
            [self processData:responseData];
        });


        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self DisplayNews];
        });       

    }); 

}];

[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error in downloading : %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Don't go that way. You're doing threading of threading. What is your actual need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my answer will help with your issue - [Here i am trying to call my ASIHTTP request in a GCD . But Completion block and failed blocks are not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702015/here-i-am-trying-to-call-my-asihttp-request-in-a-gcd-but-completion-block-and/8201604#8201604)

In short - don't use GCD. use ASINetworkQueue.

**EDIT:**

Jonathan, I wasn't comparing. Your current solution is just incorrect.

What you're doing right now, is starting an asynchronous request, which is an operation performed on a different thread. In the completion/error blocks, which will be performed on the same different thread, you ask for some global queue (i.e. thread), and move all operations to it.

The problem is that GCD is not magic, just a very successful ambiguation of threading. It assumes that it starts on the main thread, and moves back and forth between threads.

If you're really bent on learning the hard way, then here are my thoughts on your usage of GCD:

I assume you're trying to get the data, parse it and update the GUI using the DisplayNews method. if so, and also assuming you must use a global queue and not create a queue of your own, This is how you should do it:

```
    dispatch_async(JSONProcessingQueue, ^{

        NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
        [self processData:responseData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self DisplayNews];
        });       

    });
```

Comment: I don't want to compare GCD Queues and ASINetworkQueue. Here i am using GCD Queues and want to know is i am doing correct . Check my edited question

Comment: thanks now i got my prblm. So i can omit the GCD from my code . when i am using Asyncronous , it is running on the background thread ..right ?.

Comment: all this code in my NewsParser Class . So can i call the method like this NewsParser *newsParser = [[NewsParser alloc] init]; [newsParser getNews]; [newsParser release];

Comment: But the request still in background thread , so can i call [newsParser release]; its getting SIGABRT error .... but when i am using GCD there is no error ...

Comment: When you used GCD, I think it just didn't work, so this error may be unrelated to threading. Can you add the code and the exception you're getting so I can take a look?

Comment: Btw, if this is a class you're using a lot, you might want to make it a singleton and reuse it. That way, you save up alloc/dealloc, which take up some resources

Comment: thanks , i have one more doubt in ASIHTTPRequest that i didn't get any clear info ..... is the RequestFinished method called in Main Thread ?

Comment: Yep, requestFinished is called on the main thread (http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/9c42665943b9942d/a801585ad41cc87f?lnk=gst&q=RequestFinished#a801585ad41cc87f), but you can subclass ASIHTTPRequest and change that specifically. There is even a comment related to this in the ASIHTTPRequest.m file